# jackson databinding version 2.9.5 unable to parse the object to JSON String

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

We have upgraded the version of Jaxkson-databinding,jackson-core and jackson-annotation api from 2.8.2 to 2.9.5.
After this upgrade my object is getting to blank json string if I am using (for 2.8.2 the same code is working fine)

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setVisibilityChecker(
        mapper.getVisibilityChecker().
        with(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```

but the same works fine if I change the code to in version 2.9.5

```
        mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getSerializationConfig()
        .getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
        .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY)
        .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```

I can not find any change in the version upgrade relate to this in the change set of the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in the first part of your code you disabled visibility of the fields on your POJO when using [JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.html)

And in the second part you [enabled visibility for public getters of your POJOs](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-auto-detect.html).

Comment: yes but if i use the same in 2.8.2 it is working fine

Comment: There was an issue [reported in Jackson Github with non-working NONE option](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1031) in v.2.8.x.  So actually what you get is a result of bug fix.

Comment: I am facing a new problem with 2.9.5

I have an object which has another object which has a character array if that is null I am getting the below error when I use objectmapper.writeValueAsString this worked fine with 2.8.2

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.czen.core.pagination.ScrollableList["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.czen.core.value.ContentCommentValue["serviceId"])

Comment: It does not seem related to version of Jackson library.  You should mark such fields with `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` annotation.

Comment: I added that to the getter method but that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I have not mentioned that you're actually referring not an array (as you've said above) but its specific element [0].
Thus, NullPointerException indicates a flaw in the class design - here you could be referring a non-initialized object like this: `class MyObject { private AnotherObject anotherObject = new AnotherObject();

    private char someChar = anotherObject.getCharArray()[0];
}`
I managed to reproduce similar issue for any version of Json Library: 2.8.2, 2.9.5, 2.10.3.  Thus, this problem seems to be off-topic of the initial question.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61363098/arraylist-nullpionterexception) has been reported and closed today as duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

There was an Issue in Version 2.9, wich is solved with 2.9.5. show here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9.5 and https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1947.

Maybe you should try out with 2.9.4. And if your code is working on 2.9.4. It could be affected by the change.